# Adding an array of strings and HTMLDivElements using *ngFor to DOM

Tags: html, angular, typescript, innerhtml, ngfor

I have a requirement for layout something like this
[image]

I want to use CSS `display: grid;`

```js
someFunction(data) {
        this.data = data;
        let parentDiv1 = document.createElement('div');
        parentDiv1.className = 'div';
        parentDiv1.textContent = 'Random Inner Text';
        let cb1 = document.createElement('input');
        cb1.type = 'checkbox';
        cb1.className = 'check-box';
        parentDiv1.appendChild(cb1);
        this.tableKey = [
            '',
            `Text: ${this.data.someRandomText1}`,
            `Text: ${this.data.someRandomText2}`,
            `Text: ${this.data.someRandomText3}`,
            `Text: ${this.data.someRandomText4}`,
            `Text: ${this.data.someRandomText5}`,
            parentDiv1,
            `Text: ${this.data.someRandomText6}`,
            `Text: ${this.data.someRandomText7}`,
            `Text: ${this.data.someRandomText8}`,
            parentDiv1
        ];
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="table">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of tableKey" [innerHTML]="item"></ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what the output is (Ignore CSS).

[image]

Now instead of `[object HTMLDivElement]` I want a checkbox and text there. Is there a way?

Comment: Could you share the data here.

Comment: Data is just an array of strings `data=<string[]>[]`

Comment: You need to update your data set and implement that. for example your tableKey will be array of object.

Comment: you can see this. I have changed your data type and implement if else logic 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yfbr39?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Yes, this is a solution but I am looking for a way to pass an array of `strings | HTMLElement` from `.component.ts` to `.component.html`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xnoapc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Does that work for you? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7wfby2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach to this solution would be using `outerHTML` property of the created element. And then sanitize it in the HTML component using a pipe.

```js
// .component.ts

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  tableKey: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    let parentDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
    parentDiv1.className = "div";
    parentDiv1.textContent = "Random Inner Text";
    let cb1 = document.createElement("input");
    cb1.type = "checkbox";
    cb1.className = "check-box";
    parentDiv1.appendChild(cb1);
    this.tableKey = [
      "Random 1",
      "Random 2",
      "Random 3",
      "Random 4",
      "Random 5",
      "Random 6",
      parentDiv1.outerHTML,
      "Random 7",
      "Random 8"
    ];
  }
}

// .pipe.ts

import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from "@angular/core";
import {
  DomSanitizer
} from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value: string) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let item of tableKey" [innerHTML]="item | safeHTML">
  </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wy3fyq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: So basically you just copied my answer?

Comment: Not exactly. I mean there are similarities but this is a very common solution.

Comment: How is it different from the stackblitz I posted 24 hours ago? This is exactly the same code

Comment: The code is similar to what @naman posted and I made changes in that code.

Comment: The only change being to add the missing pipe (which I already did) and add `parentDiv1.outerHTML` , which I already did. Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

**Method #1**

You could use the `outerHTML` property of the html element so that your array only contains string, and then sanitize these strings in the template so that the html can be displayed

*component.ts*

```
this.tableKey = ["text1", "text2", 
  parentDiv1.outerHTML, //Convert html element to string
```

*component.html*

```
<div *ngFor="let item of tableKey" [innerHTML]="item | safeHtml ">
```

**Method #2**

Only use one array of mixed strings/HtmlElements like in your example, and in the template decide how to display it based on the type

*component.ts*

```
this.tableKey = ["text1", "text2", 
  parentDiv1, //array of mixed elements

// ...
public isString(value: any)
{
  return typeof(value) ==='string';
}
```

*component.html*

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of tableKey" >

  <div *ngIf="isString(item)" [innerHTML]="item"></div> <!-- display string -->
  <div *ngIf="!isString(item)" [innerHTML]="item.outerHTML | safeHtml" ></div> <!-- display html element -->

</ng-container>
```

See [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7wfby2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)